# Force resize and convert any image while uploading

Tags: php, image, upload, resize

I would like to force the resize and convert any image while uploading.(?)

```
if ( $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/png" || $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/gif" ) 
    {
      if ($_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/png" || $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/gif" || $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/jpg" ) 
      {
      $file=$_FILES["ufile"]["tmp_name"];
      list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
        $new_width = 200;
        $new_height = 500;
      $dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
        $src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["ufile"]["tmp_name"]);
        imagecopyresized ($dst_image, $src_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

      imagejpeg(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($dst_image)), "convert.jpg");
       $actual_image_name = $name[$i].'.'.'jpg';
       move_uploaded_file("convert.jpg", $path.$actual_image_name);
      }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: result nothing no image uploaded

Answer (score 0):

One problem I can see is this (missing array indices):

```
$file=$_FILES["ufile"]["tmp_name"];
...
$src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["ufile"]["tmp_name"]);
```

You are missing the index there so when you try to get the dimensions, the results will not be what you expect them to be.

You need:

```
$file=$_FILES["ufile"]["tmp_name"][$i];
...
$src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["ufile"]["tmp_name"][$i]);
```

Apart from that you should enable error handling and display so that you can easily catch problems like these. You can do that by adding something like this to the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

**Edit:**

You should not use `move_uploaded_file()` on a file that is not a file upload and you also need to use the image resource that you just generated for the first parameter of the `imagejpeg` function:

```
$actual_image_name = $name[$i].'.'.'jpg';
imagejpeg($dst_image, $path.$actual_image_name);
```

Comment: error report is this
Notice: Undefined variable: file_name in C:\apache2triad\htdocs\pppp\admin\upload.php on line 56 Warning: move_uploaded_file(../data1/images/): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\apache2triad\htdocs\pppp\admin\upload.php on line 56 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\apache2triad\temp\php9CE1.tmp' to '../data1/images/' in C:\apache2triad\htdocs\pppp\admin\upload.php on line 56

Comment: the code was correct when i used it for convert any pic to jpg but when i put the code of resize the result was this.

Comment: ok  ..  image  uploaded but dimensions still the same of source